# How can I catch the fact that a procedure is missing?

Tags: exception, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with Progress-4GL Release 11.6, using appBuilder and procedure editor.

I just forgot to write a procedure, causing my application to "crash" (at least, that's how it looks like it). Obviously, when my application "crashed", I didn't know that it was caused by a missing procedure, so I started experimenting with exception handling, with following results:

This is working:

```
SESSION:ERROR-STACK-TRACE = TRUE. // in order to see the callstack
DO ON ERROR UNDO, THROW:
  MESSAGE "This is nonsense: [" INT("blabla") "]" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
CATCH eAnyError AS Progress.Lang.Error:
  MESSAGE
      "Error Number:~t" eAnyError:GetMessageNum(1) "~n"
      "Error Text:~t" eAnyError:GetMessage(1) "~n"
      "Callstack:~~t" eAnyError:CallStack
      VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX BUTTONS OK TITLE "Error processing in the CATCH-clause".
END CATCH.
END.
```

This means: the situation where a wrong conversion is done (a typical programming problem), the exception is catched and the corresponding information is shown on screen.

However, this one seems not to work:

```
DO ON ERROR UNDO, THROW:
  RUN I-do-not-exist.
CATCH eAnyAppError AS Progress.Lang.<xxx>Error:
  MESSAGE
      "Error Number:~t" eAny<xxx>Error:GetMessageNum(1) "~n"
      "Error Text:~t"   eAny<xxx>Error:GetMessage(1) "~n"
      "Callstack:~~t"   eAny<xxx>Error:CallStack
      VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX BUTTONS OK TITLE "Error processing in the next CATCH-clause".
END CATCH.
END.
```

For your information, the `Progress.Lang.<xxx>Error` entry means that I've tried for the following cases:

- `Progress.Lang.Error`
- `Progress.Lang.ProError`
- `Progress.Lang.AppError`

None of those seems to work (the code compiled, but didn't catch the problem).

Does anybody know how to catch such kind of problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy answer is to upgrade to OpenEdge 12, where STOP conditions can be CATCH'ed in a CATCH block :) (it's available the more recent OpenEdge 11.7 service packs as a tech-preview too).

In OE11.6, you'll need to handle STOP conditions in the "traditional" way. Using this sample, you "transfor" the STOP condition into an error, that can be CATCH'ed from the next blck on.

```
DO ON ERROR UNDO, THROW
   ON STOP UNDO, RETURN ERROR NEW Progress.Lang.AppError ("A Stop Condition has occurred", 0).
```

As you're using DO ON ERROR UNDO, THROW on a simple, block it might be worth pointing out, that you can make THROW the default for any block in a compile-unit using the

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW .
```

directive at the top of your program. In AppBuilder programs, the Procedure Setting dialog provides a sub-dialog for USING statements - that's where you can add the BLOCK-LEVEL directive too.

Comment: Not possible with the `STOP` approach.

Comment: @nwahmaet: I already feared for that: `MESSAGE` means that you ask the application to show a message, while `STOP` means that the application has stopped, and you can't ask a stopped application to do something. :-) Right?

Comment: You can get a`CallStack` from a caught Stop exception, but not when you use the `DO ON STOP` approach Mike mentions.

Answer (score 3):

If `I-do-not-exist` is an external procedure, then you can add guards.

```
if not search('I-do-not-exist') eq ? then
    run I-do-not-exist.
```

You could create an include file that does this for you

```
//run.i &prog
if not search('{&prog}') eq ? then
    run {&prog}.
```

You can also check for internal procedures using the `INTERNAL-ENTRIES` attribute. Something like the below

```
if lookup('I-do-not-exist', this-procedure:internal-entries) gt 0 then
    run I-do-not-exist.
```

These approaches suffer from requiring devs to add the code to each RUN statement, whereas catching STOP conditions is less intrusive, and probably broader in scope.